# SoftLayer API Product_Package 200 getItemPrices returns mulitple (including invalid) priceIds for the same location group issueGrouID

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I use the following API to get item price for item id=4281, 4.00 TB SATA disk

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package
/200/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[item,id,
locationGroupId,hourlyRecurringFee,recurringFee]&objectFilter={itemPrices:
{item:{id:{operation:*=4281}}}}
```

It gives two priceIds for the each same location group including invalid priceIds.

```
itemId=4281, locationGrouID=545, priceId=57241,68071
itemId=4281, locationGrouID=503, priceId=66971, 68063
itemId=4281, locationGrouID=505, priceId=68065, 68605
itemId=4281, locationGrouID=507, priceId=68067, 57009
itemId=4281, locationGrouID=583, priceId=153059,153159
itemId=4281, locationGrouID=509, priceId=68069,57131
itemId=4281, locationGrouID="", priceId=21209,21211
```

Can somebody please fix this API to make it return only single valid priceId for different locationGrouID ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue the prices are different from each other, for example:

> priceId=57241,68071

the priceId "57241" is valid for all disk (disk1,disk2,etc) except for the disk0, which means that you cannot use this price for the disk0 of your server. The priceId "68071" is valid only for the disk0.

The same behavior is for all the prices that you listed. In order to know which price is valid for what kind of disk you need to see the categories of the price. Try this request and you will see the categories:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/200/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[categories,item,id, locationGroupId,hourlyRecurringFee,recurringFee]&objectFilter={"itemPrices": {"item":{"id":{"operation":"*=4281"}}}}
```

Regards